# How can I check if element is in Class.models.all()?

Tags: python, django

I want to check if some elements are in objects.all or not. I have class Profile which objects.all are `<QuerySet [<Profile: firstuser Profile>, <Profile: seconduser Profile>]>`. So I want to know if there is my element in HTML jinja templates.

Comment: `Profile.objects.all()` contains, well, all Profiles, so normally all such profiles will be elements. Especially since Django's equality check, only check if the primary key is the same.

Comment: op do you mean to test if a certain profile is in Profile.objects.all()? why not just use `Porfile.objects.filter()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
if Profile.objects.filter(pk=some_value).exists():
   print("EXIST") # Do something
else:
   print("NOT EXIST") # Do something
```